# SSIS: How to prevent Flat File Destination from writing multiple lines?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016

I have a task that creates a .idx file for every row in a DB. each file is supposed to have 1 text string on line 1like this:

```
"xxxx,xx,xxxxxxx,xxx_formType_xxxxx_first_M_Last,docType,first,M,Last,Path"
```

However, I am getting this:

```
"xxxx,xx,xxxxxxx

,xxx_formType_xxxxx_first_M_Last,docType,first,M,Last,Path"
```

How can I prevent it from starting a new line?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is your input text has linebreaks in it. There are various ways to filter those. The best way, however, is to filter them directly on the source.